# Passing values between workflow tasks

Tags: workflow, alfresco, activiti

I have a problem with passing property values between tasks. For example, in a start task I have defined a property:

```
<type name="mcwm:submitStart">
        <parent>bpm:startTask</parent>
        <properties>
            <property name="mcwm:projectName">
                <title>Naziv projekta</title>
                <type>d:text</type>
                <mandatory>true</mandatory>
            </property>
```

In my share-config-custom.xml I show that property on the start page and that's ok.

```
...
<show id="mcwm:projectName"/>
...
<field id="mcwm:projectName" set="general" />
...
```

Now on my second form I want to show the same field with the value that has been entered in the start form. In the model I didn't specify again this property for the second task, I just wrote:

```
...
<type name="mcwm:preparationOfProjectCharter">
   <parent>bpm:workflowTask</parent>
</type>
...
```

And in the share-config-custom.xml, I copied the first form configuration for the second form with one little change in the force="true" attribute:

```
...
<show id="mcwm:projectName" force="true"/>
...
<field id="mcwm:projectName" set="general" />
...
```

Now the field is there in my second form, but the value that is entered on my first form isn't - do I have to do something else to accomplish that and pass property values between forms?

Regards, 
Aleksadnar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you need to do something extra. See the [Workflowadministration Wiki](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/WorkflowAdministration#Process_Data).

You need to pass variables through the workflow-context, either via mapping as shown in the Wiki or through the context itself (at least for JBPM, and probably also for Activiti)

Comment: Thanks man on your help. :) I read that wiki but wasn't so clear to me so i posted here. Anyway i gained to pass values between tasks, i put on task complete task properties on my process and now they are available to all tasks.

Comment: Cool, glad to be of any help!